# How to Convert TextBox value from database to an intger in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using following code..

```
        int TotalCost = 0;
        int Price = int.Parse(txtprice.Text);
        int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantity.Text);
        int Discount = Convert.ToInt32(txtdiscount.Text);

        TotalCost += (Discount * Quantity);
        int NetCost = TotalCost * (1 - (Discount / 100));

        txtnetcost.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalCost);
```

`txtprice.Text` is coming from database. while i am trying to convert txtprice.Text it gives format exception error

Comment: what is `txtprice.text` when you get exception.

Comment: Are you sure `txtPrice.Text` can be formatted into an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `int.TryParse` it will not give you `exception` even the `value` is not a `valid int` which is to be converted.

```
int Price = 0;
int.TryParse(txtprice.Text.Trim(),out Price);
```

Also `Trim` the value of `textbox` because it may contain `extra spaces` while it was saved in `database`.